# Merging localstorage with ajax

Tags: php, ajax

How would I merge these two bits of code and can someone explain what the key and value would be. 
I'm building a notifications system and I'm wanting to store the last new notification_id but not have it inserted into the div over and over again if its the same one, so then the ajax searches for anything else within my server that maybe new.

Ajax

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function loadIt() {
      var notification_id="<?php echo $notification_id['notification_id'] ;?>"
    $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "viewajax.php?notification_id="+notification_id,   
    dataType:"json",
    cache: false,
    success: function(dataHandler){
    }
    });
    }
    setInterval(loadIt, 10000);
    </script>
```

Localstrorage

```
window.localStorage.setItem('key', 'value');
var dataHandler = function (response){
   var isDuplicate = false, storedData = window.localStorage.getItem ('key');

   for (var i = 0; i < storedData.length; i++) {
     if(storedData[i].indexOf(response) > -1){
        isDuplicate = true;
     }
   }
   if(!isDuplicate){
     storedData.push(response);
   }
}; 

var printer = function(response){
   if(response.num){
      $("#notif_actual_text-"+notification_id).prepend('<div  id="notif_actual_text-'+response['notification_id']+'" class="notif_actual_text"><a href="'+response['notification_id']+'">'+response['notification_content']+' </a><br />'+response['notification_time']+'</div></nr>');

      $("#mes").html(''+ response.num + '');
    }
};
```

Comment: you need to turn the localStorage properties (which are atrings) into objects to use handy sub-properties like that. JSON.parse/stringify works well for many data shapes. to prevent duplicates, you can look for an existing id matching ("#notif_actual_text-"+notification_id) before you append and abort early if one is in the dom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've confused oldschool Ajax by hand with jQuery. The parameter to the `success` function in jQuery is not a function name or handler. Its a variable name that will contain the response from the server.  The success function itself is equivalent to the handler functions you would have created doing it the old way.

So not:

```
 success: function(dataHandler){ }
 ...
 ...
 var dataHandler = function (response){
```

But rather:

```
 success: function(response) { doCallsToSaveToLocalStorage(response); }
```